# iOS / swift: two rows with same dequeue nib and identifier

Tags: ios, swift

I have a table view that has several sections, two sections are almost identical but their header names are different. so I have one registered nib and I'm using it in two rows:

```
self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ImprestDetailInfoHeaderTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "PaymentsReceiptsDetailsHeader")
```

and In my cellforrowat for table view I have this:

```
case 2:
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PaymentsReceiptsDetailsHeader", for: indexPath) as! ImprestDetailInfoHeaderTableViewCell
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            cell.headerType = ImprestDetailInfoType.payment
            cell.checkedAndTotalNumber = self.imprestViewModel.getStringCheckedAndTotalNumberOfPayments()
            self.paymentHeaderDelegate = cell
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AddImprestPaymentsReceiptsDetailTableView", for: indexPath) as! ImprestReceiptPaymentDetailTableViewCell
            cell.imprestItems = self.imprestViewModel.getPaymentsImprestItems()
            cell.delegate = self.imprestViewModel
            return cell
        }
    case 3:
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PaymentsReceiptsDetailsHeader", for: indexPath) as! ImprestDetailInfoHeaderTableViewCell
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            cell.headerType = ImprestDetailInfoType.receipt
            cell.checkedAndTotalNumber = self.imprestViewModel.getStringCheckedAndTotalNumberOfReceipts()
            self.receiptHeaderDelegate = cell
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AddImprestPaymentsReceiptsDetailTableView", for: indexPath) as! ImprestReceiptPaymentDetailTableViewCell
            cell.imprestItems = self.imprestViewModel.getReceiptsImprestItems()
            cell.delegate = self.imprestViewModel
            return cell
        }
```

as you see first row of 2nd and 3rd sections have identical definitions. when I click on either of these rows, I need them to show their detailed information and I change an image icons on headers, but this seems to be have a conflicting behaviour, so when I click on first row, this changes icons of both and similar strange things. Is there any chance that this problem be cus of that two cells use same nib identifier?
cus I checked my delegates and I found no problem there, the only thing I can think is some bug in swift memory management for these situations.

**UPD**: didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 1 {
        self.delegate?.summartySectionDidTapped() 
    } else if indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 0 {
        self.paymentsDetailIsOn.toggle() 
        self.paymentHeaderDelegate?.detailHeaderSelected() 
    } else if indexPath.section == 3 && indexPath.row == 0 {
        self.receiptsDetailIsOn.toggle() 
        self.receiptHeaderDelegate?.detailHeaderSelected() 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hello, when do you change the header icons / show the detailed info? Is it done in the `didSelectRowForIndexPath` or is it just a button / gesture recognizer on the cell itself? Could you show that part of code, please?

Comment: `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.section == 1 {
            self.delegate?.summartySectionDidTapped()
        } else if indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 0 {
            self.paymentsDetailIsOn.toggle()
            self.paymentHeaderDelegate?.detailHeaderSelected()
        } else if indexPath.section == 3 && indexPath.row == 0 {
            self.receiptsDetailIsOn.toggle()
            self.receiptHeaderDelegate?.detailHeaderSelected()
        }
    }`

Comment: sorry for bad formatting, I'm new to stack over flow :)

Comment: thanks, no problem :) In the future you can simply edit the question. I went ahead and did it for you in this case :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed

```
self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ImprestDetailInfoHeaderTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "PaymentsReceiptsDetailsHeader")
```

to

```
self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ImprestDetailInfoHeaderTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "PaymentsDetailsHeader")
    self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ImprestDetailInfoHeaderTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ReceiptsDetailsHeader")
```

and it seems that the problem fixed!!! (different ids for different cells)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert an header in sections you can use the function `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?`
Is more simple to implement the tableView as you want

Comment: it's not a simple header, It has imageicon and it has functionality ( I need to click on it as I said) :)

Comment: Well you can create an header with all the components and the function you want :)